# Patching variable in a python function with unittest and mock

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I have the following my_func.py with create_config function.

*my_func.py

```
from fabric.state import env

def create_config(node_name):
    config = {
    "log_level": "INFO",
    "addr1": "127.0.0.1",
    }
    config["addr2"] = env.host
    return config
```

I tried the following approach to mock env.host variable where env is an import from fabric.state.

*test.py

```
import unittest
import my_func
import mock


class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.master_config = {
              "log_level": "INFO",
              "addr2": "0.0.0.0",
              "addr1": "127.0.0.1",
        }

    @mock.patch('env.host')
    def test_create_consul_config(self, mock_host):
        mock_host.return_value = "0.0.0.0"
        result = my_func.create_config('master')
        self.assertDictEqual(self.master_config, result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I am getting import error with 'env'. What is the best way to mock variable within a function with python mock.

```
ImportError: No module named env
```

Comment: the code says `provision` but you label the file `my_func.py` which one is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> mock variable `env.host`?

get the type of `env` first

```
In [6]: from fabric.state import env

In [7]: type(env)
Out[7]: fabric.utils._AttributeDict
```

`env.host` is instance variable of a class, the mock is a little different, mock_env is object(AttributeDict), the assignment of instance_variable host is direct assignment, not with a return_value

```
@mock.patch('my_func.env')
def test_create_consul_config(self, mock_env):
    mock_env.host = 'xxx'
    result = my_func.create_config('master')

    self.assertDictEqual(self.master_config, result)
```

Comment: now getting AttributeError: host, I can see the "0.0.0.0" in mock_host object's return_value but it is not being assigned to config["addr2"]

Comment: @Anish, actually looking back, `@mock.patch('my_func.env')` make more sense than mock env.host

Comment: @Anish, the host is a instance variable, which ends up with different patching technique

Answer (score 0):

From the [unittest.mock documentation on patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) (note `target` is the first argument of `patch`):

> target should be a string in the form 'package.module.ClassName'. The
>   target is imported and the specified object replaced with the new
>   object, so the target must be importable from the environment you are
>   calling patch() from. The target is imported when the decorated
>   function is executed, not at decoration time.

So you need to include the full path to the function you are patching. Note also in [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id5) that the target should be the path to where the function/object is used, not where it is defined.

So changing your `patch` call to:

```
@mock.patch("my_func.env.host")
```

should fix the `ImportError`.